# What are we extending when creating a generic extension method?

Tags: c#

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void Print<T>(this T theObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The print output is " + theObject.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the given class I've specified a generic as the type to extend via the `this` keyword.  Being that I've delayed the definition of the type until compile time, how does intellisense (and anything else involved) know what type I am extending?  Does C# simply default to the top level `System.Object`?

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn the whole fluent sytnax in linq is based on extension methods.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The fact that LINQ is based on extension methods doesn't make all extension methods LINQ related.

Comment: @Servy Ive just wrote whats the connection  ( there are other things which arent related). extension methods DOES releated(!)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn `What does this have to do with LINQ?` topic==extension method ???? so `What does extension method have to do with LINQ?`  ? answer = fluent syntax. thats all.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - This question popped in my head during my study of LINQ.  The question itself really doesn't require a LINQ tag, I just had LINQ on the mind.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Being that I've delayed the definition of the type until compile time, how does intellisense (and anything else involved) know what type I am extending? Does C# simply default to the top level System.Object?

Those that say that this is an extension on `System.Object` are wrong. For one, this method will not box value type inputs, but an extension method defined on `System.Object` will.

The extension method you've defined is an generically parameterized extension method. It can be applied to any type **that is valid as generic type parameter**.

If you're not already thinking about extension methods in the following way, this might help you understand them a little bit better. Extension methods are just a trick that the language specification lets us get away with. Extension methods are really just static methods in static classes that we can call as if they were instance methods. So

```
static class Foo {
    public static void M(this object obj) { }
}
```

is just a static method in a static class. You could call it like this:

```
Foo.M(obj);
```

but we can call it like it's an instance method:

```
obj.M();
```

Thus, when you have a generic extension method, stop for a minute and think about it as a static method in a static class

```
static class Foo {
    public static void M<T>(this T obj) { }
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
object obj;
Foo.M(obj);
```

or you can call it like this:

```
obj.M();
```

There's no difference to the compiler which you write.

So, now you're thinking of it as a regular generic method. But surely when you think about it from this perspective you understand that the compiler will let you invoke this method on any type that is valid as a generic type parameter. And thus, you now understand why it can be thought of as an extension method on any type that is valid as a generic type parameter.

Comment: +1 That is useful information to know.  How is it that the trick works?  Are we to assume this is syntactic sugar? In other words, does the compiler simply convert the call of `obj.M()` to `Foo.M(obj)`?

Comment: Yes, it is just syntactic sugar. See 7.6.5.2 of the language specification. In particular, the statement "the method call is then processed as a static method invocation" is made in that section.

Comment: @jason 95% info about sytatic sugar and 5 % about `What are we extending ` please supply **proof** that we are not extending system.object .

Comment: @RoyiNamir: First off, I want to point out a difference between a generic extension method and an extension method on `System.Object`. The former will not box value type inputs but the latter will. Second, understanding the syntactic sugar helps unravel what is going on here.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Third, is `static class Foo { public static void M<T>(T obj) { } }` a generic method or a method defined on `System.Object`? Well, that's obvious. It's a generic method. But then, adding `this` in front of the second `T` just makes it an extension method, and invocation of it like it's an instance method is just syntactic sugar for the first example in this comment. QED.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's `System.Object` unless you add a type constraint.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Generic **parameters** (`Print<MyType>()`) can, not constraints (`where T : SomeType`).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I meant that you dont have to add the type. T

Comment: Extending on object is not the same thing as extending on all types that all valid as generic type parameters. It is not an extension on `object`.